# AngularUI Route Resolve Issue when Rejecting Promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have included my code below. Basically, when I am loading my view, I am using resolve to get some data. In my service, if my promise is rejected - on error - the resolve gets infinitely called. Is there a better way I should be performing this?

```
(function () {

function AppService($q, $http, $log, $timeout, pageOptionsModel) {

    return {
        getPageOptions: function () {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            var pageOptions = pageOptionsModel.getPageOptions();

            if (pageOptions === null) {
                $http.get("api/HomeApi/GetPageOptions")
                    .success(function (response) {
                        deferred.resolve(response);
                        $log.info("Successfully retriedved page options from service.");
                    })
                    .error(function (response) {
                        deferred.reject("Error");
                        $log.error("Errored while retrieving page options from service.");
                    });
            }
            else {
                deferred.resolve(pageOptions);
            }

            return deferred.promise;

        }
    }

};

function AppConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("line");

    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
        .state('line', {
            url: "/line",
            templateUrl: "app/line/lineTemplate.html",
            controller: "lineController",
            controllerAs: "line",
            resolve: {
                pageOptions: function (appService) {
                    return appService.getPageOptions();
                }
            }
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

};

angular.module("app", ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "app.line", "app.modal"])
    .config(AppConfig)
    .factory("appService", AppService);

})();
```

Here is my Line Controller which never initializes if my promise is rejected.

```
 (function () {

function LineController($scope, pageOptions) {

    var self = this;

    // INITIALIZE
    self.pageOptions = pageOptions;

};

angular.module("app.line")
    .controller("lineController", LineController);

 })();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the `LineController` is expecting `pageOptions` injected as a promise and not actually data?  Can you include controller code that processes the `pageOptions`?

Comment: Line Controller will not be initialized until the promise is resolved, so this controller will use it as data. I have included the Line Controller.

Comment: When the promise is rejected, UI Router won't keep trying to resolve the promise. Do you use state change event handlers? I'm guessing something like that is causing your code to re-enter the state when the promise gets rejected.

Comment: I am not using any events for state change currently. As soon as I comment out the rejected, or replace it with resolve, it works again. That is why I suggested it was because of that.